# selenium-rc: how to clear the network traffic logs on the selenium w/o getting them

Tags: selenium-rc, network-traffic

I perform a process using selenium (i.e open pages, click on links,..) and I want to get the network traffic only of the last page and only on error. That is, when opening a moving to a new page the "network log" on the selenium host needs to be empty. If an error occurs on the page, I call `captureNetworkTraffic` and get the last headers.

According to `captureNetworkTraffic`'s documentation this is the only function that clears the logs. The problem is that it get's the logs and I want to reduce network traffic to the selenium host. Is there a way to tell selenium to clear the logs w/o actually getting them?